# Pre checking condition before login

Tags: login

I need to check a condition with a web service (via curl) when a user is trying to log in. How do I check this conditions before login and if it throws an error how do I show like an WP error?

Thanks

Comment: Without code this is going to be hard to answer, and as it depends on a third party plugin it is likely off-topic anyway.

Comment: What code do you need? My hook file? or the plugin's code?

Comment: Probably both, which is a lot of code. That is part of the reason that questions dependent upon third party plugins are off-topic.

Comment: Take a look [at these answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A385+wp_remote_get) - what do you need? What is your question? About which plugin are you talking?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the authentication functions are pluggable, meaning you can fully override the actual functions by simply defining them in a plugin which will be loaded before the `pluggable.php` file and provide the services you declare.

Take a look at [`wp_authenticate`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L521) and [`wp_check_password`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1861). They have filters and actions in them as well that should allow you to do any pre-validation you need. In this case, it's easiest to just copy the existing functions and add your code as needed.

Based on what you've said so far though, you can probably achieve what you are trying via the [`wp_authenticate_user` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user). Just return a WP_Error if your curl request fails.

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', function ($user, $username, $password) {
  if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    // run your curl check here
    if ( ! $curling ) {
      return new WP_Error( 'curling_is_dangerous', __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> wat? ' .
          'That doesn\'t even look like a curl!' ) );
    }
  }

  return $user;
} );
```